# An implementation of a simple html context menu

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a system .Net MVC3, and I need to implement a simple html context menu that will play with a rightClick.

Thanks

Comment: More explanation please....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is jquery context menu [example](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/) and [demo](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/input.html)

[Flash context menu](http://www.milonic.com/menusample27.php)

[Adding Your Own Context Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa907671.aspx)

[javascript context menu](http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-context-menu-tutorial.htm)

Hope this helps